# Error: Could not find Google translate frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate

`Error: Could not find Google translate frame` in safari and ipad.
Here is my code:

```
<ul class="translation-links">
    <li><a href="#" class="spanish" data-lang="Spanish">Spanish</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="german" data-lang="German">German</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Code provided by Google -->
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
  }
</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.translation-links a').click(function() {
        var lang = $(this).data('lang');
        var $frame = $('.goog-te-menu-frame:first');
        if (!$frame.size()) {
          alert("Error: Could not find Google translate frame.");
          return false;
        }
        $frame.contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item span.text:contains('+lang+')').get(0).click();
        return false;
      });
  });
</script>
```

it is work fine for chrome and mozila. but not working for safari and ipad.

Comment: In which version you are checking

Comment: Thanks Mitul, i have tested with safari 5+ and it is not working in any browser of ipad.

Comment: var $frame = $('.goog-te-menu-frame:first'); -> this frame is only created once you select an option from google translate language dropdown.